# combining first_name with last_name to give full name in PHP Mailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

All of my form works well, the only thing i,m trying to achieve is combine the first_name with last_name to give full name in the email header. I'm using PHPMailer. This is the code i tried to use -

```
 $firstname = $_POST["first_name"];
 $lastname = $_POST["last_name"];
 $fullname = $firstname . ' ' . $lastname;
 $fullname = $_POST["name"];

 $mail = new PHPMailer(TRUE);
 $mail->From = $_POST["email"];     //Sets the From email address for the 
 message
 $mail->FromName = $_POST["name"];    //Sets the From name of the message
 $mail->AddAddress('timmy2872@gmail.com');  //Adds a "To" address
 $mail->WordWrap = 50;       //Sets word wrapping on the body of the 
 message to a given number of characters
 $mail->IsHTML(true);       //Sets message type to HTML
 $mail->AddAttachment($path);     //Adds an attachment from a path on the 
 filesystem
 $mail->Subject = 'Employer Application Form details';    //Sets the 
 Subject of the message
 $mail->Body = $message;       //An HTML or plain text message body
 if($mail->Send())        //Send an Email. Return true on success or 
 false on error
```

Can anyone see what i,m doing wrong??

Comment: `$mail->FromName =  $_POST["first_name"].' '.$_POST["last_name"];`

Comment: Thanks tim but didn't work either just shows the email address

Comment: there is no `From` method in phpmailer, there is a `setFrom`

Comment: If i set  $mail->FromName = $_POST["first_name"]; or  $mail->FromName = $_POST["last_name"]; it works fine, just cannot combine the 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it eventually with this -
        
       `$full_name = $_POST["first_name"] . ' ' . $_POST["last_name"]
       $mail->FromName = $full_name;`

Thanks to Tim for putting me on the right track